# How can I fix not being able to click on anything?

Tags: cursor

I booted up my computer today, and after logging in, I can move the cursor, but I can't click on anything. I've tried the laptop's internal touchpad and two external mice. None of them work.

If it matters, I'm running Ubuntu 12.10

How can I fix this?

Comment: is your device detected as a pointer device when you run `xinput --list`?

Comment: So your cursor moves. But does the computer recognize the cursor? For example, if you move the cursor over one of the apps in the Launcher on the left side of the screen and pause, does a tooltip popup showing what the icon is?